# How can I check if I am at EOF when reading a file from a CMD Batch.bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, eof

I'm trying to fill X files with chunks of content from a .txt file.
The thing is the .txt (source) file is small and I want my code to loop over it's content chunk by chunk and start again when no more chunks are avaliable until all files have been filled.

This is part of the (still on development) code. I've managed to teach my Batch.bat to recognized the chunks but I don't know how to check if I am at EOF to go back again to the begining.

Current code doesn't work since it has been simplified for the question (delayed expansion not present)

```
SET /A J=1
FOR /F "skip=%J% tokens=*" %%A IN (%~1%) DO ( 
 CALL :CSV "%%A" %J%
)
EXIT /B
:CSV
SETLOCAL
IF NOT "%~1"=="---" ( 
 ECHO %~1 >> Chistaco.txt
)
ENDLOCAL && SET /A J=%2+1
```

Code posted here is just a guide of my target, don't miss the question.

Thank you !

EDIT: Simplified Code Module

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM Ask for parameters
SET /P filler=Enter the name of the file to use as filler (file.ext): 
SET /P seed=Enter the seed of the files to fill: 
CLS && ECHO %~1%

REM The variable "J" counts the lines to jump in "file.ext" (and btw, it cannot be 0 as the batch parses fails to read it)
REM This is where the EOF check is needed: "J" must be referenced outside the main loop so the script can loop inside "file.ext" untill all "seed???" files have been filled
SET /A J=1
FOR /R "%path%" %%X IN (%seed%*) DO ECHO %%X && CALL :FillerChomper "%filler%" "%%X"
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B

:FillerChomper
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "skip=%J% tokens=*" %%A IN (%~1%) DO ( 
 CALL :CSV "%%A" J %2%
 IF "%%A"=="---" EXIT /B
)
EXIT /B

:CSV
SETLOCAL
IF NOT %1=="---" ECHO %~1 >> %~3%
ENDLOCAL && SET /A %2=%J%+1
EXIT /B
REM All functions must have a "EXIT /B" command or batch will just keep executing codelines until :EOF
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: You need to nest your FOR loop inside another loop. Exactly how you do that depends on 'X". You did not describe 'X'. Is 'X' a few files that are fixed names; a few files whose names are passed as parameters; thousands of files; files in a fixed folder(s); list of file names in another text file?????

Comment: Hi, @RGuggisberg. I'm on a little workaround consisting in measuring the file.txt before reading the chunks, but your idea looks prettier to me. Will work on both things and post the whole result in a new post (will leave a link here, ofc).

X is not the matter right now, don't worry about it :) but if you feel courious, X is a list of files in a directory that fit into a *seed???.ext*, where 'seed' is a fixed string and '???' is a serial number, so this code will take a chunk of text, fill it into "seed001.ext" and move to the next and so on. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does the called :CSV routing need a `GOTO:EOF` somewhere?

Comment: Hi, @Liturgist. There is no need of a GOTO anytime. Just a check. But turns out you don't need it since batch already knows when it is EOF. RGuggisberg's answer is the right one. Will post full chunk of code son so you see it. Thanks!